# Position 5 divs randomly

Tags: javascript, html, function, random

I'm completely stuck here. I'm trying to create a program where i have 5 different divs. They need to be placed at random position when running the program. And they need to switch position when i drag my mouse over them. So far i've done this. (which is completely wrong).

```
   function Init()
   {
   div = document.getElementById("pixel");
   div = document.getElementById("pixel1");
   div = document.getElementById("pixel2");
   div = document.getElementById("pixel3");
   div = document.getElementById("pixel4");

   spaceW = screen.height - div.height;
   spaceH = screen.width - div.width;
   setTimeout(moveIt, 0);
   }
   function moveIt()
   {
   div.style.top = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
   div.style.left = (100*Math.random()) + "%";
   }

<body onload="Init()">
    <div id="pixel" style="background-color:blue; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"/>
    <div id="pixel1" style="background-color:green; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"/>
    <div id="pixel2" style="background-color:orange; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"/>
    <div id="pixel3" style="background-color:yellow; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"/>
    <div id="pixel4" style="background-color:red; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"/>
</body>
```

Can someone nudge me in the right direction because this clearly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added your code to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x05b5suz/2/

Few things I would like to tell you:

```
div = document.getElementById("pixel");
div = document.getElementById("pixel1"); // This is wrong
div = document.getElementById("pixel2");
```

You should declare your variable with `var` keyword and their name should be unique in a scope of a function otherwise you are just overwriting them. So you can name them `var div1`, `var div2` so on.

In HTML, you need to close your `<div>...</div>` tags, div are not supposed to be quick closed.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much Pal! Just one thing, one you run the program, all the divs are stuffed in the upper left corner. Is there a possibility so when you run the program, they're already placed randomly? Now you have to drag the mouse over it first. Can i change it using <body onload? Or something similiar. Cheers!

Comment: In fiddle, `Init()` method gets executed after its definition and divs are randomly placed `onload` event. In fiddle,  script and html are in different file and their script execute onload event it works there. I'm assuming you have your html and script in one file, so you can do `<body onload="Init()">`

Comment: If your script and html are in one file, I will suggest to move your script out to a new `.js` file and then in your script do `window.onload = Init` at the bottom. and remove `<body onload...`

Answer (score 2):

**check out** after fix some syntax error like **Pal Singh** mention
 AND

- add all div(s) to one array so can be easy to control it
- add [**getRandomNum() , percentwidth() , percentHeight()**] functions to keep div(s) in page
- add **moveIt()** function to do some animation when move

```js
 function RandomIt()
 {
    var div_array = [];
    div_array.push(document.getElementById("pixel"));
    div_array.push(document.getElementById("pixel1"));
    div_array.push(document.getElementById("pixel2"));
    div_array.push(document.getElementById("pixel3"));
    div_array.push(document.getElementById("pixel4"));
    div_array.forEach(function(entry) {
        moveIt(entry,getRandomNum(1,100 - percentwidth(entry)),getRandomNum(1,100 - percentwidth(entry))) 
  });
 }
 function getRandomNum(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }
 function percentwidth(elem){
     return ((elem.offsetWidth/window.innerWidth)*100).toFixed(2);
 }
 function percentHeight(elem){
     return ((elem.offsetHeight/window.innerHeight)*100).toFixed(2)+'%';
 }
 function moveIt(elem,target_x,target_y) {
   var pos_x = 0;
   var pos_y = 0;
   var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
   function frame() {
     if (pos_x == target_x && pos_y == target_y) {
       clearInterval(id);
     } else {
      if(pos_x < target_x){
    pos_x++; 
         elem.style.left = pos_x + '%'; 
   }
   if(pos_y < target_y){
    pos_y ++;
    elem.style.top = pos_y + '%';
   }
       
        
     }
   }
   }
```

```html
<body onload="RandomIt()">
    <button onclick="RandomIt()">RandomIt</button>
    <div id="pixel" style="background-color:blue; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"></div>
    <div id="pixel1" style="background-color:green; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"></div>
    <div id="pixel2" style="background-color:orange; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"></div>
    <div id="pixel3" style="background-color:yellow; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"></div>
    <div id="pixel4" style="background-color:red; position:fixed; height:50px; width:50px; font-size:25px;"></div>
</body>
```